# I'm new in PHP CodIgniter, I have some wrong syntax error with MySql "Delete Join"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-delete

```
 public function delete($group_id)
 {
      $this->db->where('t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, t4.*, t6.*, COUNT(t5.id) AS total_students')
               ->join('groups_days AS t6', 't1.group_id = t6.group_id') 
               ->join('groups_members AS t5', 't1.group_id = t5.group_id')
               ->group_by('t1.group_id')
               ->delete("groups AS t1")
               ->result();
 }
```

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `t1` WHERE t1., t2., t3., t4., t6.*, COUNT(t5.id) AS total_students' at line 1
>
> DELETE FROM `groups` AS `t1` WHERE t1., t2., t3., t4., t6.*, COUNT(t5.id) AS total_students
>
> Filename: D:/www/domains/uzdev/taraqqiyot/application/models/Group_model.php

My delete not working and showing above error. What is wrong here

Comment: I've edited my question, you can check now

Comment: Well, clearly `WHERE t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, t4.*, t6.*` makes little sense. What exact meaning do you expect from it?

Comment: I want to delete by id, I already did add

Comment: I think he want's to delete row from "groups" table and other rows from related tables "groups_days", "groups_members" as well

Comment: Yes, I want to do like that, but I cannot find the way how to describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link you can't do delete with join with CodeIgniter Active Records:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581239/code-igniter-deleting-data-with-joins-tables)

Another option is using several queries as many as number of tables:

```
$this->db->delete('groups', array('group_id'=>$group_id));
$this->db->delete('groups_days', array('group_id'=>$group_id));
$this->db->delete('groups_members', array('group_id'=>$group_id));
```